# Angularjs How to make route async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using route and ngView to load dynamic content, and I got warning:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

The warning is from jQuery 2.1.3

If I try to load a static html file it works fine without any warning, is there anyway I can make routing asyc?

app.config(function($routeProvider){

```
$routeProvider.when("/test", {
    templateUrl: "/getStuff",
    resolve:{

    }
})

$routeProvider.otherwise({
templateUrl: "/test.html",
resolve:{

}
});
```

});

If I try to load a static html file, it works without warning, if the templateUrl is not a static html file, there will be a warning

Comment: I think you might want to consider a service to load content asynchronously. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: I can't make out what you're asking.  Post some code?

Comment: app.config(function($routeProvider){

 $routeProvider.when("/test", {
  templateUrl: "/getStuff",
  resolve:{

  }
 })

 $routeProvider.otherwise({
 templateUrl: "/test.html",
 resolve:{

 }
 });
});

Comment: so if it's a static file, it will work (ending in html one), if it's a url, it works but with the warning

Comment: what does jQuery have to do with angular routing?

Comment: I have used some plugin that requires jQuery and the warning is from jQuery

Comment: The warning is from the browser. I get this warning in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem! it's because the html I return from the url contains

```
<link href="..." rel="stylesheet">
<link href="..." rel="stylesheet">
<script src="..."></script>
```

So it make requests during loading, thank you guys